# Excel file upload using Tornado

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-upload, upload, tornado

I am writing a file upload using Torando. My API will receive only one excel file and save it in a folder. However, right now, I keep getting file corrupted error.

Here's the basic code of the API

```
def post(self):
        user = {
            "name": "Test"
        }
        if user:
            if "test_file" not in self.request.files:
                return self.write(json_util.dumps({
                    "message": "Required excel file missing.",
                }))
            bulk_excel = self.request.files['test_file'][0]
            original_fname = bulk_excel['filename']
            extension = os.path.splitext(original_fname)[1]
            fname = ''.join(random.choice(
                string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(12))
            final_filename = fname+extension
            output_file = open(final_filename, 'w')
            output_file.write(bulk_excel['body'])
```

Now I have also tried to write `open(final_filename, 'wb')` but, it did not work as intended.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the error you faced?

Comment: `open(final_filename, 'wb')` should work

Comment: If you mean to write the contents of the Excel file as text (something like CSV) then you need a way to read the Excel file format (with something like https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)